# Picking a particular directory path using os path in Python

Tags: python, os.walk

I have a root directory, which is for example `~/abc`. To get the full path of this root directory, I am using

```
root_dir = os.path.expanduser('~/abc')
```

Within, `abc`, I have sub directories `xyz` and `bin`. To get the full paths of these, I am using

```
for path, dirs, files in os.walk(root_dir, topdown=False):
    print path
```

I get the following output

```
/home/user/abc/xyz/bin
/home/user/abc/xyz
/home/user/abc
```

Now, suppose I want to extract only the full path of the `bin`, how do I go about?. I am not interested in the paths of `xyz` or `abc`

Comment: how you set your `root_dir` and loop it to show this output should get you again to do this with `/home/user/abc/xyz/bin`, what's the problem really?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for path, dirs, files in os.walk(root_dir, topdown=False):
    if 'bin' in path:
        print path
```

Another way would be using `split`:

```
for path, dirs, files in os.walk(root_dir, topdown=False):
        if path.split('/')[-1] == 'bin':
            print path
```